# Transfer iPhoto Library to other computer using Terminal

Tags: macos, path, terminal, file-transfer

I want to move my iPhoto library from one MacBook to my MacBook Pro.  If I connect in Finder and transfer, it shows a time of about a day.  I heard that if you use Terminal to transfer, it speeds it up greatly, but I can't seem to get it.  Could someone see if there is an error in my line in terminal?

```
cp -r /Users/candace.brassfield \(Deleted\)/Pictures/iPhoto Library /afp://Candace's MacBook Pro.local/Brassfield/Pictures/
```

Comment: How are you transferring your files? WiFi? Using Ethernet or even FireWire target disk mode will greatly speed this up. Not sure what effect using the command line will have.

Comment: Also, this isn't a programming question, so it shouldn't go on stackoverflow.

Comment: Using wifi.  I've seen lots of similar questions to this on stack overflow.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to mount disk:

```
mkdir /Volumes/macbook_pro
mount_afp "afp://Candace's MacBook Pro.local/Brassfield/Pictures" /Volumes/macbook_pro
cp -r /Users/candace.brassfield\ \(Deleted\)/Pictures/iPhoto\ Library /Volumes/macbook_pro
```

Comment: I got this      mount_afp:  AFPMountURL returned error -1069, errno is -1069

Comment: Seems that can't find the server